# Error in setting Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have the following structure :

[image]

How do you display the two questions in Discussion object by using `FirebaseListAdapter`? The below code did not give desired results

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Discussion"); 
myAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this,String.class,android.R.layo‌​ut.simple_list_item_‌​1,myRef) { 
  @Override 
  protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) { 
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1); 
    text.setText(s); 
  } 
}; 
GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView); 
gv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Discussion"); myAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myRef) {
                @Override
                protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {
                    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    text.setText(s);
                }
            };
        GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Comment: How do you access the unique key in  DatabaseReference ?

Comment: @Ros: I added the code into your question. There is an edit link under your question that allows you to make improvements like that.

Comment: Aside from that: what's the problem?

Comment: How do you display the two questions in Discussion object by using FirebaseListAdapter? The above code did not give desired results.

Comment: What's the result you're expecting?

Comment: It is working fine..I made an error in code which I now corrected. Thank u everyone for the help.